# Объект с подсчетом ссылок на него

Tags: c#, .net

Хотелось бы узнать как правильно реализовывать такую структуру классов, в зависимости от которых как пример, при вызове метода освобождения ресурсов, у класса который зависит от текущего, уменьшить количество ссылок на объект который создавался при помощи того на кого он ссылался, и при достижении количества ссылок равным нулю, объект так сказать самоликвидировался *(освобождал неуправляемые ресурсы, и становился невалидным)*.

В `C++` это бы сделать не составило труда, задать приватный метод, и подружить данный класс с теми кто может увеличивать/уменьшать количество ссылок. Но как хотя бы примерно такое реализовать на `C#` ума не приложу.

Необходимо все это дело для реализации фабрики.

Comment: Делать освобождение ресурсов в финализаторе. За ссылками автоматически следит сборщик мусора: когда он удалит объект, тогда сработает финализатор.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Сборщик мусора не интересует. Интересует именно такой вариант который был описан в вопросе. Время жизни объектов критично.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите. Может приведете пример на С++?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно добавить в класс счетчик ссылок

```
public class Foo : IDisposable
{
    private int _refCounter = 0;
    public void IncRef() { _refCounter++; }
    public void DecRef() 
    {
        _refCounter--;
        if(refCounter <= 0) Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Dispose impl here
    }

}
```

А в классе, которому будет присваиваться этот объект в свойстве необходимо реализовать увеличение количества ссылок при `set` и уменьшение при перезаписи

```
public class Bar
{
    ~Bar()
    {
       FooInstance = null;
    }

    private Foo _FooInstance;
    public Foo FooInstance
    { 
       get => return  _FooInstance;
       set 
       {
           _FooInstance?.DecRef();
           value?.IncRef();
           _FooInstance = value;
       }
    }
}
```

Но тут проблема в том, что ссылки будут считаться только когда объект будет присваиваться к полям, а в случае переменных это работать не будет. Однако этой задачей занимается сборщик мусора, а если необходимо освобождать ресурс, как только он перестал использоваться, то, наверное этот "костыль" должен подойти, но более правильным подходом было бы найти места в коде, где ресурс точно должен освобождаться и вызывать метод `Dispose`. Но, если это невозможно, то самым правильным способом было бы использование финализатора. Как правильно его объявить для `IDisposable` можно посмотреть [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/dispose-pattern).

Если используется `unmanaged` ресурс, то есть смысл использовать для этого [`SafeHandle`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle?view=netframework-4.7.2), в нем, если я не ошибаюсь, подсчет количества ссылок реализован на уровне компилятора.